# How to print coloured blocks to console?

Tags: rust, colors

I have come across the following code in Rust and was wondering how to replicate these coloured blocks into my own code. Is there a way to type down these blocks?
[Here is the code mentioned.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JZd6.jpg) (editted to include code as text below)

```
for s in word_state {
                let temp = match s {
                    CharState::Green => "",
                    CharState::Yellow => "",
                    CharState::Red => "",
                    CharState::Unknown => "⬛",
                };
```

Comment: It looks like that code should work just fine for creating strings with those colored blocks. Does printing the `temp` string not work?

Comment: sorry for not making myself clear, I was wondering how to type these coloured blocks into the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do this in two ways: either using the Unicode characters for the colored squares emojis or you can use ANSI escape codes if your terminal supports them.

If you want to use Unicode characters, you can just put them inside strings:

```rust
fn main() {
  println!("Red: ");
  println!("Yellow: ");
  println!("Green: ");
}
```

To obtain those characters, you can either press `win + .` on windows or copy-paste from [here](https://whatemoji.org/blog/emoji-color-series-circle-square-heart/) on any other platform.

---

You can also use ANSI escape characters, which are a bit more powerful since they can also color text.

```rust
fn main() {
  println!("Red: \x1b[41m  \x1b[0m");
  println!("Yellow: \x1b[43m  \x1b[0m");
  println!("Green: \x1b[42m  \x1b[0m");

  // Combine them to create complex results
  println!("\x1b[32m\x1b[44mGreen Text with blue background\x1b[0m");
}
```

[ANSI escape codes on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors)

Comment: I really discourage such methods. One should never use ANSI escape codes directly, but we must ask to a good library (libcurses, tc, ..). The above method assumes you have an ANSI terminal, which it is not always the case (e.g. some windows `cmd`, redirecting output to a central dashboard/server, etc.). So either check terminal capabilities (and user terminal preference) and act according it, or just let a library to do it.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Yeah, that is true, but the same applies for emojis: not all terminals support unicode symbols. So both methods are technically wrong.

Comment: Right, but colours are more annoying: we often do redirects, logs, and search for strings on outputs. Emoji will just be displayed wrongly, but often transparently so they may be ok in a copy. Note: it is ok to be lazy, but I think it is important to point out possible problems (depending on the use of the program)

Answer (score 0):

These squares are just Unicode characters, similar to Unicode-based Emoji. You can either use a software-keyboard to enter them or copy&paste them from a Unicode reference page like https://www.emojiall.com/en/unicode-subhead/V2

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate Marcus' annswer with code example:

```
fn main() {
    // format of unicode escape sequences uses braces
    // To use Unicode 1F7E5 for RED Square use:
    println!("RED Square: \u{1F7E5}");
    
    // Or copy paste the symbol into code:
    println!("RED Square: ");

}
```

[Link to Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3cf1a4eddf81770ec0760b43657f0207)